# AS3: How to use GTween?

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, tween

I'm working with the latest version of the SDKs and FlashDevelop.  So far, everything about my setup works fine, including external libraries.  But when I use [GTween](http://gskinner.com/libraries/gtween/), nothing happens.  At all.  I've tried several of the included samples and some of my own code, and all I get is a blank window or nothing moves, respectively.  No errors, but also no action.

Could someone paste in some minimal code that just loads GTween and has it move a sprite?  I'd like to have a known good for comparison so I can see if I'm missing something obvious or if there's something weird going on.

Thanks!  :)

Comment: There is no better library than TweenMax for AS3, dude you really MUST check it out.

Comment: The GreenSock tweeners come highly recommended, but they also come highly priced for commercial use.  $150/year, which I find kind of ludicrous.

Comment: depends if you charge your users

Comment: can you paste what has not worked? have you seen the documentation yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i just downloaded GTween and copied the com folder to my source...

... this worked fine:

```
package{
   import com.gskinner.motion.GTween;

   import flash.display.Sprite;

   public class GtTest extends Sprite{

     public function GtTest(){
           var ball:Sprite = new Sprite();
           ball.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
           ball.graphics.drawCircle(300,300,10);
           addChild(ball);
           var myTween:GTween = new GTween(ball, 2, {x:100, y:100}, {swapValues:true});
      }
   }
}
```

hope that helps ;)

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I needed.  And, strangely, it works perfectly.  But at least I have a point to start investigating from now.  Thanks a bunch!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're compiling to the version of flashplayer you have? It's possible that your player needs to be updated. Hard to tell from this info what could be the problem.

Also GTween is ok, and I have it in one project and used it fairly recently, but there are better alternatives. (gtween was last updated in 2009)

I've been using [eaze](http://code.google.com/p/eaze-tween/) a lot, but I know most as3-ers flock to TweenLite (for a good reason).

Comment: I skipped TweenLite because of the high pricetag for commercial use.  But I'll check out eaze and see if it works out any better for me (though it also hasn't been updated in a year).  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: TweenLite/TweenMax is free for commercial use. Unless you charge the final user for the content.